# Visual Studio DB Ignore FileGroups

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2017

From a Visual Studio DB project i have set the option to exclude filegroups as well as ignore file filegroup placement. When I generate the publish script, the below SQL statement is added to the publish script. The default filegroup in the database is not PRIMARY, so i understand why the below is being added. Being that i set the options to exclude filegroups I was hoping that this SQL statement would not be included. Is it possible to exclude filegroups? Is there another option I'm missing?

```
ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
MODIFY FILEGROUP [PRIMARY] DEFAULT;
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and Sql Server 2008 R2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to stop SqlPackage.exe setting default Filegroup in deployment script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42498706/is-there-any-way-to-stop-sqlpackage-exe-setting-default-filegroup-in-deployment)