# Azure Pipelines - Integration Tests with local SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

For the integration test we are are making use of the SQL Server database.
The integration tests are currently running on a Self-Hosted Agent which contains a local installed SQL Server.

I want to get rid of the self-gosted agents and move the integration test to an Azure pipeline (windows-latest)

According to the documentation I found on https://github.com/actions/runner-images there is no local SQL Server installed.
I found some documentation about starting the SQL Server Express LocalDB (which is stangly enough not on installed software list)

```
sqllocaldb start mssqllocaldb
```

But when I deploy my dacpac with SqlPackage I gen an error

For publishing the dacpac I use:

```
- powershell: |
    dotnet tool update -g microsoft.sqlpackage
   
    $database='$(Database)'    
    & SqlPackage /Action:Publish `
            /SourceFile:$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\Database\Database.dacpac `
            /TargetServerName:'(localdb)\.' `
            /TargetDatabaseName:$database `
            /p:AllowIncompatiblePlatform=true `
            /p:CreateNewDatabase=false `
            /p:AllowUnsafeRowLevelSecurityDataMovement=true `
            /P:DropObjectsNotInSource=true `
            /p:DoNotDropObjectTypes='Logins;Users;Permissions;RoleMembership'    
  continueOnError: true
  displayName: 'Publish Database'
```

The deployment fails with the error:

```
Error SQL72014: Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 5120, Level 16, State 108, Line 1 Unable to open the physical file "C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\MSSQLLocalDB\aaaaa_MemoryFileGroup_6D53B7E9.mdf". Operating system error 0: "(null)".
Error SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:
ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
    ADD FILE (NAME = [MemoryFileGroup_6D53B7E9], FILENAME = N'$(DefaultDataPath)$(DefaultFilePrefix)_MemoryFileGroup_6D53B7E9.mdf') TO FILEGROUP [MemoryFileGroup];
```

How to proceed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In combination with the question: [Is there any way to stop SqlPackage.exe setting default Filegroup in deployment script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42498706/is-there-any-way-to-stop-sqlpackage-exe-setting-default-filegroup-in-deployment) the following setup works  now.

First create the database

```
 sqllocaldb delete MSSQLLocalDB
 sqllocaldb create MSSQLLocalDB -s
 sqllocaldb start MSSQLLocalDB
 
 $sql = "CREATE database $(Database)"
 SqlCmd -d 'master' -S '(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB' -W -h -1 -Q $sql
```

Then in the second step:

```
  dotnet tool update -g microsoft.sqlpackage
 
  $database='$(Database)'    
  & SqlPackage /Action:Publish `
          /SourceFile:$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\Database\Database.dacpac `
          /TargetServerName:'(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB' `
          /TargetDatabaseName:$database `
          /p:AllowIncompatiblePlatform=true `
          /p:CreateNewDatabase=false `
          /p:AllowUnsafeRowLevelSecurityDataMovement=true `
          /P:DropObjectsNotInSource=true `
          /p:ExcludeObjectTypes=Filegroups `
          /p:DoNotDropObjectTypes='Logins;Users;Permissions;RoleMembership'
```

The options which must be set:

```
/p:CreateNewDatabase=false        <-- database is already present
/p:ExcludeObjectTypes=Filegroups  <-- No MemoryFile
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Local DB is installed together with Visual Studio or SSDT I suspect.

> ### Connect to the automatic instance
>
> The easiest way to use LocalDB is to connect to the automatic instance owned by the current user by using the connection string `Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Integrated Security=true`. To connect to a specific database by using the file name, connect using a connection string similar to `Server=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Integrated Security=true;AttachDbFileName=D:\Data\MyDB1.mdf`.

From the docs:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511&view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Local test works.
I'm using this...
$server='(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB'
$database='$(Database)'    
& SqlPackage /Action:Publish `
        /SourceFile:...Database.dacpac `
        /TargetServerName:$server `
        /TargetDatabaseName:$database `
        /p:CreateNewDatabase=true `  ..etc
Result:...
Creating SqlFilegroup [MemoryFileGroup]...
An error occurred while the batch was being executed.
Error SQL72014: Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 5120, Level 16, State 108, Line 1 Unable to open the physical file....Instances\MSSQLLocalDB\xxx_MemoryFileGroup_2EA321A2.mdf

Comment: Even this fails...
- task: SqlDacpacDeploymentOnMachineGroup@0
  inputs:
    TaskType: 'dacpac'
    DacpacFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\Database\Database.dacpac'
    TargetMethod: 'connectionString'
    ConnectionString: 'Data Source=(localdb)\.;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=xxx'

Answer (score 0):

> Error SQL72014: Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 5120, Level 16, State 108, Line 1 Unable to open the physical file . Operating system error 0: "(null)".

From the error message, we can confirm that the connection with SQL Server Express LocalDB is successful.

The cause of the issue is related to the following command:

```
ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
    ADD FILE (NAME = [MemoryFileGroup_6D53B7E9], FILENAME = N'$(DefaultDataPath)$(DefaultFilePrefix)_MemoryFileGroup_6D53B7E9.mdf') TO FILEGROUP [MemoryFileGroup];
```

You are using the FileStream which doesn't supported by SQL Server Express LocalDB.

Refer to this doc: [SQL Server Express LocalDB Restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver16#restrictions)

> LocalDB doesn't support FILESTREAM.

In this case, you may still need to use Self-hosted agent with the local installed SQL Server.

Comment: THat is strange, because when I'm using the same commands on my local development machine it works like a charm....

Comment: @Bart Are you using SQL Server Express LocalDB or  local installed SQL Server on your local machine? The limitation exists in the SQL Server Express LocalDB. If you are using local installed sql server, it will work as expected

Comment: I'm assuming that when I deploy to (localdb)\. and when I'm connecting to locally: (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB and this is also visible in my MSSMS that i'm looking at the SQL Server Express LocalDB.
btw The FILESTREAM options in the Database Settings of the database project are off

Comment: I think I misunderstood. But No i'm not making use of the FILESTREAM (varbinary) type

Comment: Can you check the command in your project: `ADD FILE (NAME = [MemoryFileGroup_6D53B7E9], FILENAME = N'$(DefaultDataPath)$(DefaultFilePrefix)_MemoryFileGroup_6D53B7E9.mdf') TO FILEGROUP [MemoryFileGroup];` If possible can you share some code snippet? then we can check this issue further